# unable to connect to chromedriver - incompatibilty with the gem 'extlib'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I have integrated latest version of selenium-webdriver with capybara and cucumber. 
If I try to run rake tasks with firefox as selenium driver, then getting the error of 'Childprocess:LaunchError' and if set chromedriver as default selenium driver then it throws an error of 'unable to connect to chromedriver '.

As suggested, I have set all the chromedriver path. Also used gem "chromedriver-helper". But none works.

Answer (score 0):

I start checking all the gems to check the incompatibilty with some gem and found the solution.

gem "extlib" is creating the incompatibility issue. On uninstalling this gem, everything works fine. As this app was first made in rails 2 so this gem was used at that time.